# Unscented Kalman Filter weightings

Tags: kalman-filter

I'm trying to understand the weightings used in the Unscented Transform, as part of the Unscented Kalman Filter.

The transformation uses weightings in the calculations of the mean and covariance. By definition these weightings must sum to 1 in each case. There is a popular way to assign the weightings which is (see for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWDzmweTKsQ&t=1478s)) $$ w_m^{[0]} = \frac{\lambda}{n+\lambda}$$ $$w_c^{[0]} = w_m^{[0]} + (1-\alpha^2 + \beta)$$ $$w_m^{[i]} = w_c^{[i]} = \frac{1}{2(n+\lambda)}, \qquad i=1, \dots, 2n$$ where $w_m^{[i]}$ and $w_c^{[i]}$ are weightings for the mean and covariance, respectively.

The parameters are set as $\alpha \in (0,1]$, $\beta = 2$ and $\lambda = \alpha^2(n+\kappa)-n$ for $\kappa \ge 0$. The parameter $n$ is the dimension of the distribution.

However, if $w_m^{[i]} = w_c^{[i]}$ for $i=1, \dots, 2n$, how can they both sum to 1? Clearly there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm presented here is for Van der Merwe scaled sigma points. There is no unique way to choose the sigma points, and in this case, the weights aren't required to sum to one.